# Lat-Lon-Tools -> no external map choosable

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

Since today (dont know why!) I can't select an external map in the Lat-Lon-Tools-Settings. I already uninstalled the AddIn, deleted the User-Folder and reinstalled it. Same: there is no option in the drop-down-field... ;(

[image]

From the log...

```
2020-08-15T20:57:28     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\latlontools\settings.py", line 552, in showEvent
              for item in settings.userMapProviders:
             TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I think it is a bug (because there was a update). I installed an old version (latlontools-3.3.13) and it works)

Comment: Suggest you [submit an issue](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-latlontools-plugin/issues) to the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this was a bug and is now fixed:

https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/qgis-latlontools-plugin/issues/50